# ASP.NET - Connect to website via LAN

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, lan

I created ASP.NET MVC application and I need to connect to it from another device (that is connected to the same network). How can I do it? I start the application from visual studio and I need to do it just once.

Hosting device: device A

Another device: device B

I started the application in device A and it worked, but I couldn't connect from device B. I turned off firewall, but device B displayed error 400 (The request hostname is invalid). I've tried to fix it by opening IIS config file and changing `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":60618:localhost" />` binding information to `"*:60618:*"`, `"*:60618:"`, `":60618:"` - in all cases, visual studio shuts down right after I click "start" button.

How can I connect to my ASP webapp from device B?

Thanks, Peter

---

EDIT: Solved

The problem was, I had to use both binding protocols. So the config file should look like this:

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":60618:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":60618:*" />`

And the second problem was, that I had to start Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: First host your application on local IIS and then try using device A's IP address and the port name on which your application can be accessed. ex: 192.168.0.1:60618

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. I was using device IP address, I just configured the IIS config file badly. Thank you for response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The asterisk in the binding worked. Here is the full guides:

https://www.theancientscroll.com/tech/4-steps-aspnet-web-apps-lan/753/